# Condition on duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 4 columns:

user id, start date (D/M/Y), type and name

```
user_id | start_date | type | name
1       | 1-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
1       | 1-01-2017  | 1    | Jack
1       | 2-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 3-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
1       | 4-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 5-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
```

I want to retrieve data by id ,type and start date .But the condition is, I want only single record, if date is same and priority is where type = 1 . Don't want duplicate dates. I already tried Group by but it shows only where type is 0.

### I want Like this :

```
user_id | start_date | type | name
1       | 1-01-2017  | 1    | Jack
1       | 2-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 3-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
1       | 4-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 5-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
```

### GROUP BY Result :

```
user_id | start_date | type | name
1       | 1-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
1       | 2-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 3-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
1       | 4-01-2017  | 0    | Jack 
1       | 5-01-2017  | 0    | Jack
```

Comment: You want to retrieve data by id, type and start_date.
Do you mean order them by those columns?

Comment: No, I don't want to order them. I want , If any date is duplicate then between these two dates, show only where type is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply select the `MAX(type)` from your data:

```
SELECT user_id, start_date, MAX(type) AS x_type, name
FROM testdata
GROUP BY user_id , start_date, name
```

This returns one row per each `user_id, start_date, name` tuple:

```
| user_id | start_date | x_type | name |
+---------+------------+--------+------+
| 1       | 1-01-2017  | 1      | Jack |
| 1       | 2-01-2017  | 0      | Jack |
| 1       | 3-01-2017  | 0      | Jack |
| 1       | 4-01-2017  | 0      | Jack |
| 1       | 5-01-2017  | 0      | Jack |
```

Comment: Thanks !! Problem is solved . I was not putting MAX  and secondly GROUP BY start_date; gave me exact result.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand what exactly are you looking for, but the following query, will give you the exact results you are looking for:

```
SELECT MAX(user_id) AS user_id, 
  start_date,
  MAX(type) AS type, 
  MAX(name) as name
FROM data AS d1  
GROUP BY start_date;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c370/1)**:

```
| user_id |           start_date | type | name |
|---------|----------------------|------|------|
|       1 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |    1 | Jack |
|       1 | 2017-02-01T00:00:00Z |    0 | Jack |
|       1 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z |    0 | Jack |
|       1 | 2017-04-01T00:00:00Z |    0 | Jack |
|       1 | 2017-05-01T00:00:00Z |    0 | Jack |
```

Comment: Thanks !! Problem is solved . I was not putting MAX .